# how to change Devexpress Grid Row color without event

Tags: c#, winforms, visual-studio, devexpress

I have a form with a UserControl containing a grid of a vehicle list and I want to pass a List of vehicle IDs and a color to method and in that method I want to find each Index of the Datasource where the Vehicle ID is in the DataSource.

With those index I want to get the RowHandle (or directly the row object) and change the backcolor with the color I passed in the parameters.

```
private void ApplyColorRow(List<int> vehicleID, Color color)
{
  var Index = 0;
  // foreach view the Datasource 
  foreach (var View in this.VehicleViewList)
  {
    // if the list of VehicleID contains the vehicleID
    if (vehicleID.Contains(View.VehicleData.VehicleID))
    {
      // find the Row handle corresping to the datasource index
      var RowHandle = this.gvVehicle.GetRowHandle(Index);
      // Get the row object
      // This return an object corresponding to the View (VehicleView in my case)
      // But I need the Row object to change the appearance.
      var Row = this.gvVehicle.GetRow(RowHandle); 
      // Row.BackColor = color;
    }
    Index++;
  }
}
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Unless you handle the **GridView** **RowStyle** event, any changes you attempt to make will be immediately undone once the grid refreshes itself.

Is there a reason you don't want to use an event to set the row color?  You could simply cache what the color of each **vehicleID** should be, and then set the appropriate color in the **RowStyle** event.

Here's the DevExpress documentation that outlines customizing row appearances:
https://documentation.devexpress.com/#WindowsForms/CustomDocument758

Comment: the only reason its because i didnt want to change RowStyle at "loading time", but i found a workaround wiht GridView.RefreshRow(int rowHandle) and handling RowStyle event. thanks

Answer (score 0):

If you have finite number of conditions, you can actually do this without any events (even RowCellStyle), using the format conditions within the Grid designer.  If you enter design mode and select "Appearance," and then "Format Conditions," you can add a series of format conditions and their corresponding effect.

There is a property for each format condition called "Apply To Row," where you define a condition for a single column, but the format can either apply only to that column, to other columns or the entire row.

The disadvantage is for each color you need one format condition, unless you hijack the designer code into your form code (which is not necessarily a bad idea).

If System.Color is actually the datatype of one of your properties, and you have an indefinite (or large) number of possibilities, then the `RowCellStyle` event is the way to go.

By the way, per your last comment, you can always disable `RowCellStyle` during load and renable it after the `Shown` event completes.

Comment: What if I wanted to change the appearance of a random row, knowing only its rowHandle?  This is not my actual use case, but is analogous: what if I wanted to give the user mouse-training exercise by making them click on "the red row", and the row that is red keeps changing every few seconds and stays red only for 500ms?   Knowing only the rowHandle, how do you get a reference to an object that would let you set the row's appearance?

Comment: @Tim -- that's probably more than you can reasonably accomplish with the Format Conditions, but you should still be able to do it with the `RowCellStyle` event and a Windows Timer.  When you create the event handler, you will notice an `e.RowHandle` you can use to do what you describe.